# What is the probability that the contestant chooses at least one of the top 5 most valuable boxes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> In the game show “Deal or no Deal?”, a contestant must first choose 5 boxes out of 22
> to be opened. Each box contains a different amount of money. Once a box has been
> opened, its contents can no longer be won.
>
> What is the probability that the contestant chooses at least one of the top 5 most valuable boxes?

I started this question by splitting it up into five cases:
Case 1 - Choosing exactly 1 of the top five most valuable boxes
Case 2 - Picking exactly 2 of the top five
Etc.
Thinking about case 1, I would do 5C1*17C4 (this would give the number of ways of choosing 1 of the top 5 boxes, multiplied by the number of ways of choosing 4 boxes that aren't in the top 5)
Apply this method to all the cases.
Assuming this is correct, I am unsure of how to continue once the values for each case has been obtained. Do I add them up and divide by 22C5?

Comment: Why not think instead of the complement  instead of cases ?

Comment: The complement being 17C5/22C5 right?

Comment: Yes, that is the complement representing P(*not* choose any of the top $5$ boxes), but you need one more step to get the answer you need.

Comment: As indicated by @trueblueanil, you want $~\displaystyle 1 - \frac{\binom{17}{5}}{\binom{22}{5}}.$

Comment: When a question contains 'at least' or 'at most', always consider the complement ; very often, the new question is more simple.